# Optimise rendering when loading images in React/Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Right now I am trying to load a collection of cards from Firebase Firestore and using Storage to load the Images of the cards, but when i try to load the cards with componentswillmount, the images are not loaded to the card(I believe it is because the function is returning the card objects before the images URLs are loaded, so i have to render again using the right/left buttons). That is why i would like to know how to do it so the whole card(image included) is loaded correctly without having to render again. I have seen many other post about this but don't quite get to solve the issue(after trying different solutions)
I leave the image to the code and how the cards are seen before and after the re render :D

Code:

```
export async function getAllIDs(){
  const q = query(collection(db, "Books"));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  let array= [];
  let it=0;
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    var data = {};

    data.id=doc.id;
    data.Title=doc.data().Title;
    data.Summary=doc.data().Summary;
    data.Image=doc.data().Image;
    array[it]=data;
    it++;
    console.log(data);
  
  getDownloadURL(ref(storageRef, doc.data().Image))
  .then((url) => {
  // Or inserted into an <img> element
    console.log(url);
    data.url=url;
    
    });
  });
  console.log(array);
  return array;

}
```

[before re render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGsw2.png)

[after re render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id54q.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Right now, your loop on querySnapshot isn't waiting for each getDownloadURL to complete before the getAllIDs returns, which is why your images aren't appearing when you expect. You shouldn't use forEach to iterate querySnapshot in this case. That makes it impossible to use await on getDownloadURL, which is really what you want to do.  Instead, iterate the snapshot using a for loop so you can await getDownloadURL inside that loop.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your loop on querySnapshot isn't waiting for each getDownloadURL to complete before the getAllIDs returns, which is why your images aren't appearing when you expect. You shouldn't use forEach to iterate querySnapshot in this case. That makes it impossible to use await on getDownloadURL, which is really what you want to do. Instead, iterate the snapshot using a for loop so you can await getDownloadURL inside that loop.